# Adding a relationship to a manytomayfield?

Tags: python, django, many-to-many

views.py - I am trying to retweet(add a many to many relationship) to my users tweets but I keep getting the below error. It works fine when I add a relationship in the admin. It shows up on my template just fine but when I try to do this operation in my view it just does not seem to work, I have not done a lot of work with Django so I need some serious help I've checked the docs and other questions but can not seem to find anything relevant.

--> 'RelatedManager' object has no attribute 'retweet'

```
  def retweet(request,user_id, tweet_id):
    logged_user = request.user.userprofile.tweet_set
    user_want_to_retweet = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    user_profile_want_to_retweet = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, user=user_want_to_retweet)
    get_tweet = Tweet.objects.filter(userprofile=user_profile_want_to_retweet, id=tweet_id)
    add_retweet = logged_user.retweet.add(get_tweet)
    return HttpResponse('Retweeted')
```

models.py

```
 class Tweet(models.Model):
   userprofile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
   tweets = models.TextField(max_length=120)
   retweet = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,   related_name='people_retweet', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
   date = models.DateTimeField()
```

urls.py

```
  url(r'^retweet/(?P<user_id>[\d]+)/(?P<tweet_id>[\d]+)/$', views.retweet, name='retweet')
```

My Template - combined_tweets is just a combined list and is what I am using to get all the entries(tweets), from three separate queries. I am geting the logged in users tweets, the tweets from the people that the logged in user follows and the tweets that the logged in user retweeted. But I do not believe this is where the problem is.

```
     {% for combined_tweeters in combined_tweets %}
             <ul><strong>{{ combined_tweeters.userprofile.user }} | {{ combined_tweeters }} | {{ combined_tweeters.date }} |
             {% if combined_tweeters.userprofile.user == request.user %} <a href="{% url 'delete_tweet' user_id=combined_tweeters.userprofile.user.id tweet_id=combined_tweeters.id %}">Delete </a>
             {%else%} <a href='{% url "retweet" user_id=combined_tweeters.userprofile.user.id tweet_id=combined_tweeters.id %}'>Retweet</a> {% endif %}</strong></ul>
     {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't really see what you're trying to do here. `users_tweets` is a queryset, it doesn't itself have a `retweet` property, only the individual Tweet object in that queryset do.

Comment: so then how would I add a relationship I thought that was the way you were supposed to?

Comment: Well, no. You add a relationship to an instance.

Comment: Alright, I will give it a try.

Comment: @DanielRoseman what do you mean by adding to an instance I am still having trouble.

Comment: @DanielRoseman just edited my question btw aswell

Comment: @DanielRoseman I figured it out ty for what you do for django on stackoverflow btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in my views and I was going about it the wrong way so here's the answer for anyone who needs help with this in the future, and just completely disregard user_id in the above question that is not needed, without the user_id the URL, and template they both are then fine, and in turn correct.

views.py

```
 def retweet(request, tweet_id):
   logged_user = request.user.userprofile
   get_tweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, pk=tweet_id)
   add_retweet = get_tweet.retweet.add(logged_user)
   return HttpResponse('Retweeted')
```